# How to insert comments into longer expression

Tags: vimscript

I have this rather big if statement to test if a certain cursor position is within two other cursor positions

Altogether it looks like this:

```
  " a
  " thecursor
  " b
  if (a:a[l:ROW] <# a:thecursor[l:ROW] && a:thecursor[l:ROW] <# a:b[l:ROW]) ||

    " a
    " thecursor a
          \ (a:a[l:ROW] <# a:thecursor[l:ROW] && a:thecursor[l:ROW] ==# a:b[l:ROW] &&
          \ a:thecursor[l:COL] <# a:b[l:COL]) ||

    " a thecursor
    " a
          \ (a:thecursor[l:ROW] ==# a:a[l:ROW] && a:c_a[l:COL] <# a:thecursor[l:COL] &&
          \ a:thecursor[l:ROW] <# a:b[l:ROW]) ||

    " a thecursor b
          \ (a:thecursor[l:ROW] ==# a:a[l:ROW] && a:thecursor[l:ROW] ==# a:b[l:ROW] &&
          \ a:a[l:COL] <# a:thecursor[l:COL] && a:thecursor[l:COL] <# a:b[l:COL])
    return v:true
  endif
```

However when executed I get this error:

> E15: Invalid expression: (a:a[l:ROW] <# a:thecursor[l:ROW] && 
>   a:thecursor[l:ROW] <# a:b[l:ROW]) ||

It is because you can't enter comments within a statement that is continued using `\`. Is there some way to still use comments in such a situation?

Comment: Try with `<` instead of `<#`.

Comment: I actually realized what it is: the comments. Going to edit my question...

Comment: AFIK if you can't put the comment in the middle of the expression normally, you can't put them in the middle when it's split either.

Comment: Ok, I guess I discovered another VimL idiosyncrasy...

Comment: this is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to compare numbers with any string sensitivity. You are receiving this error due to lack of escaping new lines with `\` and your use of comments.

#### Comments in expression

Vim will not understand the expression properly if you try and sandwich a comment inside of it. It would be much better to create a set of temporary variables that are well named for each portion and comment those. Example of one such variable:

```
" a
" thecursor
" b
let between_the_lines = a:a[l:ROW] < a:thecursor[l:ROW] && a:thecursor[l:ROW] < a:b[l:ROW])
```

#### Refactor

General rule of thumb: If some portion of code is repetitive and hard to understand, then it is time to refactor.

Let's create a compare function, `s:cmp`, that takes in lists and compares one list another to one item at a time returning `-1` (less than), `0` (equal), or `1` (greater than).

```
function! s:cmp(a, b)
  for i in range(len(a:a))
    if a:a[i] < a:b[i]
      return -1
    elseif a:a[i] > a:b[i]
      return 1
    endif
  endfor
  return 0
endfunction
```

By cleverly crafting our List in the form `[LNUM, COL]` we can use our `s:cmp` function to compare different positions in the file.

Example of using this code to determine if the cursor is within the visual selection:

```
let cursor = getpos('.')[1:2]
let v_start = getpos("'<")[1:2]
let v_end = getpos("'>")[1:2]

echo s:cmp(v_start, cursor) <= 0 && s:cmp(cursor, v_end) <= 0
```

I imagine this code is far simpler to understand when you come back to it at later time.

#### For more help

```
:h user-function
:h getpos()
:h List
:h range()
:h len()
```

Comment: `:h <#` brings me right to the description of the `<#` operator.

Comment: @hgiesel, You are correct `<#` does exist. However you do not need it in this case as these values are `Number`'s. The issue is the lack of escaping new lines and comments. Do not mix them